# Redirecting by role from a button

Tags: redirect, user-roles

We have a button at the top of our site where users can quickly get their account information, but we need to redirect them to different pages based on their role.
Is there code I can add to this button code to accomplish this?

```php
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in () ): ?>
   <a href="/my-account/"><span class="wbutton">My Account | Logout</span></a>
<?php else : ?>
    <a href="/connect/"><span class="wbutton">Login | Register</span></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: additional info: I have three roles that need to go to three different account pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like the code below.

```
<?php
/**
 * Use the two lines below if the user_id is not available
 * via get_current_user_id at this point in code execution.
 *
 * $user_id = apply_filters( 'determine_current_user', false );
 * wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
 */

$current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

$user_data = get_userdata( $current_user_id );
$user_roles = $user_data->roles;
$link_path = '';

if ( is_array( $user_roles ) ) {
    // Look for desired role.
    if ( in_array( 'subscriber', $user_roles ) ) {
        // Create link based on role.
        $link_path = 'subscriber_link';
    } elseif ( in_array( 'editor', $user_roles ) ) {
        // Create link based on role.
        $link_path = 'editor_link';
    } else {
        // Create default link.
        $link_path = 'default_link';
    }
}

$link_to = esc_url( get_home_url( null, $link_path ) );
$logout_url = esc_url( wp_logout_url() );
?><?php if ( is_user_logged_in () ): ?>
   <a href="<?php echo $link_to; ?>"><span class="wbutton">My Account</span></a> | <a href="<?php echo $logout_url; ?>"><span class="wbutton">Logout</span></a>
<?php else : ?>
    <a href="/connect/"><span class="wbutton">Login | Register</span></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks so much for the answer, I'm still struggling a little. I have added the code below but it is not redirecting the user based on role to the appropriate pages when I click the my account button. Any ideas on what I may need to change?

Comment: @JulieGeorge. Oops. Sorry. There is an error with a variable in my code. Change *$user->roles* to **$user_roles**. You can see the three locations where I made the changes on the [timeline page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/415693/timeline) by clicking the right-pointing triangle to the left of the word "edited". Thanks.

Comment: Nice, that works flawlessly! Thanks so much!

Comment: Great! Please remember to mark the answer as accepted (if it is correct) so others who find your question in their search results know that a correct answer is available. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
          <?php
                    /**
                     * Use the two lines below if the user_id is not available
                     * via get_current_user_id at this point in code execution.
                     *
                     * $user_id = apply_filters( 'determine_current_user', false );
                     * wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
                     */
                    
                    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
                    
                    $user_data = get_userdata( $current_user_id );
                    $user_roles = $user_data->roles;
                    $link_path = '';
                    
                    if ( is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
                        // Look for desired role.
                        if ( in_array( 'commissioner', $user->roles ) ) {
                            // Create link based on role.
                            $link_path = '/commissioner-account';
                        } elseif ( in_array( 'municipality', $user->roles ) ) {
                            // Create link based on role.
                            $link_path = '/municipality-account';
                        } else {
                            // Create default link.
                            $link_path = '/my-account';
                        }
                    }
                    
                    $link_to = esc_url( get_home_url( null, $link_path ) );
                    $logout_url = esc_url( wp_logout_url() );
                    ?><?php if ( is_user_logged_in () ): ?>
                       <a href="<?php echo $link_to; ?>"><span class="wbutton">My Account</span></a> | <a href="<?php echo $logout_url; ?>"><span class="wbutton">Logout</span></a>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <a href="/connect/"><span class="wbutton">Login | Register</span></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```